# Difficulty with .htaccess determining which file to use based on final page backslash '/'

Tags: .htaccess

I have two types of pages in a section of my website.

One is for a categories, for example:

- example.com/section/fruit/
- example.com/section/vegetables/

The other for page details, for example:

- example.com/section/fruit/apple
- example.com/section/fruit/orange
- example.com/section/fruit/grape

I am using .htaccess to grab the urlslug and talk to the database to display the right information and use the right template file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /section/(.*)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  section/(.*)/ /template/category.php?urlslug=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /section/(.*)/(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  section/(.*)/(.*) /template/detail.php?category=$1&urlslug=$2 [L]
```

Unfortunately, because I have two url display methods the above .htaccess does not work. For categories they end in a ‘**/**‘ and the page detail are open (no slash) and .htaccess file cannot work out which one to grab.

I guess the question here is two fold.

1. From a best practice point of view. Is it better to have one consistent convention for URLs (all of them having an end slash or no end slash)? My current reasoning is that pages without a slash are the end page and the ones with a slash are categories but am not sure my logic is awesome on this one.
2. Assuming what I am doing is okay from a URL structure point of view. What would be the best approach to get the .htaccess to behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules:

```
# skip below rules for files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/?$ template/category.php?urlslug=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ template/detail.php?category=$1&urlslug=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Note that `.*` matches everything. Using anchors in regex patterns allows you to match only one path component after `/section/`.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Thank you.